# Strange behaviour between wamp and lamp (ubuntu)

Tags: php, url-rewriting, apache2, wamp, lamp

Ever since I moved to Linux, I noted some strange behaviour. In Ubuntu, `http://localhost/index` works but on WAMP it does not work. **I tested this with APACHE's rewrite module set to off on both**. Any good explanation?
[image: Strange WAMP & LAM behavior]

Apache.conf (LAMP)

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Apache.conf WAMP

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

## EDIT: Why it behaves this way thanks to [tntu][2]

Because of the directive `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` on LAMP (ubuntu), the url localhost/index can resolve to the file index.php, index.html. So foo would also result into foo.php, foo.html. A proper explanation can be derived from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

### Don't be confused to think this is url rewriting

Comment: Provide your mod_rewrite statement please

Comment: mod_rewrite is off both!

Comment: So, if mod_rewrite is off, see my answer, I believe the difference is the ``DirectoryIndex`` value, or lack of it in one of the setups

Comment: What does ``conf.d/`` has? and ``sites-enabled/`` ? somewhere there has to be a DirectoryIndex

Comment: Go to ``/etc/apache2`` and there do: ``grep -r DirectoryIndex *`` and see what it returns

Comment: @nrathaus, conf.d/ has for files. charset localized-error-pages, other-vhosts-access-logs and security. Upon inspection they don't look like they are handling what I'm asking about

Comment: So use ``grep`` to locate where DirectoryIndex is being defined, it might also be in ``/etc/php[45]/``

Comment: grep -r DirectoryIndex * appended to end of question

Comment: What happens if you access ``http://localhost/?`` on both machines (the question mark is part of the URL to access)

Comment: @nrathus: Both servers show their default pages. LAMP > It works WAMP > default wamp sever page showing the apache and php versoim

Comment: Can you use Chrome and verify that both pages (using the ``Developer Tools``) are being access are the same, by looking at Chrome's captured ``Network`` traffic?

Comment: http://imgur.com/jpSd7yF - LAMP

Comment: http://imgur.com/qyFSeCt - WAMP

Comment: Sorry but you should be accessing "/?"

Comment: Apologies for that. http://imgur.com/tVDdnPF - WAMP

Comment: Wonder why this question is being voted down?

Comment: Probably, because a solution was provided, questions on how to resolve it asked, etc and the OP doesn't seem to be able to either provide them (answer), or used the provided solutions to solve his problem. So it is a "dead-end" question

Comment: @nrathaus: Tried every corner of the internet but didn't see any answer to this. Probably it's hard coded in one of LAMP's modules. Would the guys at Serverfault answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this option in Apache Conf:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Make sure you also test by removing it from Ubuntu and see if it still works. There are certain features that might have different behavior on Windows.

Comment: You're a genious!!! Adding this to apache conf on wamp worked  `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews`. So now when I type http://localhost/index it resolves to the default index page!! This is what we have in LAMP (ubuntu)!! Been trying to figure this out for YEARS!!!

Comment: I stumbled upon it accidentally a few years back. It was actually causing me trouble and needed to disable it. After reading through the  Apache docs I found it.

Comment: Someone could think its url rewriting and it's not! Probably a Q&A for this would help!!

Comment: Well it means: Follow similar links. This means if it cannot find a link it will show the most similar one. In your case index.php or whatever instead of just index. In my case it was showing 27.jpg when requesting 26.jpg that was not found.

Comment: It is properly explained under Content Negotiation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html #Notes on hyperlinks and naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the *apache.conf* file and the site configuration files are the same?

From the looks of it, one's *DirectoryIndex* is *index.php*, while the other has *index* as the *DirectoryIndex*. For more information about *DirectoryIndex* see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: I think the OP meant that he has the rewrite module turned on, on both the systems.

Comment: Even if he has a rewrite, which he didn't post here so I cannot know for sure, one shows a request for index, while the other index.php. That doesn't explain if the redirect is causing this or the server is.

Comment: Rewrite is turned off on both systems. See my text in bold!

Comment: @nrathaus: None of the directories have .htaccess

Comment: How about ``apache.conf``? or the ``sites-enabled/*.conf`` ?